# Ссылка на источник через html css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Каким образом можно реализовать такую вещь: при копирование ссылки с какого-то сайта и вставки в соц сеть, чтобы отображался блок с минимальной информацией и лого  этого сайта, вот как на этой картинке например [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Я нашел что-то типо этого

< script > document.oncopy = function() {
    var bodyElement = document.body;
    var selection = getSelection();
    var href = document.location.href;
    var copyright = "<br><br>Источник: <a href='" + href + "'>" + href + "</a><br>";
    var text = selection + copyright;
    var divElement = document.createElement('div');
    divElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    divElement.style.left = '-99999px';
    divElement.innerHTML = text;
    bodyElement.appendChild(divElement);
    selection.selectAllChildren(divElement);
    setTimeout(function() {
        bodyElement.removeChild(divElement);
    }, 0);
}; < /script>
```

Вставил перед `</body>`, но на локальном видимо не работает, хоть тут и нет кода с информацией и лого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно заглянуть в **head** страницы и посмотреть:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/img/favicon.ico?v=b95a7516ec95">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=0dd80f442adc">
<meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="name" content="Ссылка на источник через html css">
<meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="Каким образом можно реализовать такую вещь: при копирование ссылки с какого-то сайта и вставки в соц сеть, чтобы отображался блок с минимальной информацией и лого  этого сайта, вот как на этой карт...">
```

Comment: то есть это просто прописывается пере тегом head, и при копирование страницы будет так как на картинке? Я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Это прописывается в теге head. Да, будет так же. Но ссылки с локального, конечно, не будут работать

Comment: окей, спасибо вам!